# Generic ASP.NET MVC method that can be called on any model type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, generics

I want to write a function that can be called from my HomeController on a List with the type being any of my Models that have types of data to one another. The goal is to also pass in various column names that I know exist, and operate on these columns while iterating over the list.

Currently, the problem that I am experiencing is when I try to operate on the list at a certain index using the parameter of a column name I passed in, the C# is giving me an error that the item of type column that I am passing in doesn't exist for the List of a generic type, when in reality I will be guaranteeing that the columns passed in as strings exist.

The generic code is as follows:

```
public static void someOperation<T>(List<T> itemList, string colName1, string colName2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < itemList.Count; i++) {
        float newItem = ((float)itemList[i].colName1) // the variable colName1 in my list of objects is a float
    }
}
```

Please let me know if there is a better way to write a function that can be executed on a List of any type of model within my MVC structure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a constraint that tells the compiler that this property is of that type

```
public static void someOperation<T>(List<T> itemList, string colName1, string colName2) where T : MyItem 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < itemList.Count; i++) {
       float newItem = itemList[i].colName1;
    }
}

public class MyItem 
{
    public float colName1 { get; set; }
}

public class Model1 : MyItem
{
}

public class Model2 : MyItem
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Doesn't doing that defeat the purpose of passing in a generic list? I would have to have a separate function for each of my Model types where I say "where T : ModelType", which is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: If all of your models have the same property name, they all can implement MyItem, so you can have one function to do all. Updated answer above.